# Brackets and commas appearing in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the greatest product of 14 consecutive digits in a number but commas, brackets, and quotes keep appearing on line 7

```
def iteration(number):
    number = list(str(number))
    index = 0
    numbers = []
    into = 1
    for n in range(14):
        into *= int(number[n+index])
    numbers.append(into)
    index += 1
    iteration(number)
    return sorted(numbers)[0]
```

Comment: Your indentation looks wrong.

Comment: ...and those 14 consecutive digits with commas, brackets, and quotes are? I can't duplicate your problem if you don't provide all of the essentials. And please take the time to read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Problems in your code currently: 1) you pass the list called numbers directly into function iteration, instead pass it as iteration(''.join(number)) 2) Your recursion doesn't have a terminal condition, so you will get RunTimeError when recursion maxes out 3) You assume all numbers will always have 14 digits, and that is a recipe for `IndexError` when smaller number are passed in